# Adding nis.schema throwing error: invalid format (line 2) entry: ""

Tags: openldap, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to add the `nis.schema` into my LDAP base. My file looks like this:

```
attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.2 NAME 'gecos'
        DESC 'The GECOS field; the common name'
        EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match
        SUBSTR caseIgnoreIA5SubstringsMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.3 NAME 'homeDirectory'
        DESC 'The absolute path to the home directory'
        EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.4 NAME 'loginShell'
        DESC 'The path to the login shell'
        EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.5 NAME 'shadowLastChange'
        EQUALITY integerMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.6 NAME 'shadowMin'
        EQUALITY integerMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )

attributetype: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.7 NAME 'shadowMax'
        EQUALITY integerMatch
        SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
```

When I run the following command I receive the error:

```
 ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -f /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldapadd: invalid format (line 2) entry: ""
```

I read somewhere ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025462/ldapadd-invalid-format-line-1-entry-when-adding-a-schema-on-systems-inclu/23463422)) that there needs to be a `:` (as you can see it's been added). Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to load in the wrong file.
`ldapadd` requires valid `ldif` syntax, which the .schema file you are trying to load doesn't have.
Side note: I find rfc2307bis is usually a better schema to use than rfc2307(nis).

---

It's possible to convert a .schema file into a .ldif file using `slaptest`, but right now that's probably more trouble than it's worth. I am uncertain if Ubuntu, like CentOS, comes with an equivalent .ldif file, so I've added one to the end of this answer.

---

```
$ cat /etc/openldap/schema/nis.ldif
# NIS (RFC2307)
# $OpenLDAP$
## This work is part of OpenLDAP Software <http://www.openldap.org/>.
##
## Copyright 1998-2016 The OpenLDAP Foundation.
## All rights reserved.
##
## Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
## modification, are permitted only as authorized by the OpenLDAP
## Public License.
##
## A copy of this license is available in the file LICENSE in the
## top-level directory of the distribution or, alternatively, at
## <http://www.OpenLDAP.org/license.html>.
#
# Definitions from RFC2307 (Experimental)
#   An Approach for Using LDAP as a Network Information Service
#
# Depends upon core.ldif and cosine.ldif
#
# This file was automatically generated from nis.schema; see that file
# for complete references.
#
dn: cn=nis,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: nis
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.2 NAME 'gecos' DESC 'The GECOS field; th
 e common name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SUBSTR caseIgnoreIA5SubstringsMatc
 h SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.3 NAME 'homeDirectory' DESC 'The absolut
 e path to the home directory' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1
 466.115.121.1.26 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.4 NAME 'loginShell' DESC 'The path to th
 e login shell' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.2
 6 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.5 NAME 'shadowLastChange' EQUALITY integ
 erMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.6 NAME 'shadowMin' EQUALITY integerMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.7 NAME 'shadowMax' EQUALITY integerMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.8 NAME 'shadowWarning' EQUALITY integerM
 atch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.9 NAME 'shadowInactive' EQUALITY integer
 Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.10 NAME 'shadowExpire' EQUALITY integerM
 atch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.11 NAME 'shadowFlag' EQUALITY integerMat
 ch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.12 NAME 'memberUid' EQUALITY caseExactI
 A5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.
 26 )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.13 NAME 'memberNisNetgroup' EQUALITY ca
 seExactIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.11
 5.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.14 NAME 'nisNetgroupTriple' DESC 'Netgr
 oup triple' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.1.1.0.0 )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.15 NAME 'ipServicePort' EQUALITY intege
 rMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.16 NAME 'ipServiceProtocol' SUP name )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.17 NAME 'ipProtocolNumber' EQUALITY int
 egerMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.18 NAME 'oncRpcNumber' EQUALITY integer
 Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.19 NAME 'ipHostNumber' DESC 'IP address
 ' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{128} )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.20 NAME 'ipNetworkNumber' DESC 'IP netw
 ork' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{128} SI
 NGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.21 NAME 'ipNetmaskNumber' DESC 'IP netm
 ask' EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{128} SI
 NGLE-VALUE )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.22 NAME 'macAddress' DESC 'MAC address'
  EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26{128} )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.23 NAME 'bootParameter' DESC 'rpc.bootp
 aramd parameter' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.1.1.0.1 )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.24 NAME 'bootFile' DESC 'Boot image nam
 e' EQUALITY caseExactIA5Match SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26 )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.26 NAME 'nisMapName' SUP name )
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.27 NAME 'nisMapEntry' EQUALITY caseExac
 tIA5Match SUBSTR caseExactIA5SubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.
 1.26{1024} SINGLE-VALUE )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.0 NAME 'posixAccount' DESC 'Abstraction o
 f an account with POSIX attributes' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( cn $ uid $ uidNu
 mber $ gidNumber $ homeDirectory ) MAY ( userPassword $ loginShell $ gecos $ 
 description ) )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.1 NAME 'shadowAccount' DESC 'Additional a
 ttributes for shadow passwords' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST uid MAY ( userPassword
  $ shadowLastChange $ shadowMin $ shadowMax $ shadowWarning $ shadowInactive 
 $ shadowExpire $ shadowFlag $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.2 NAME 'posixGroup' DESC 'Abstraction of 
 a group of accounts' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ gidNumber ) MAY ( userPas
 sword $ memberUid $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.3 NAME 'ipService' DESC 'Abstraction an I
 nternet Protocol service' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ ipServicePort $ ipSe
 rviceProtocol ) MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.4 NAME 'ipProtocol' DESC 'Abstraction of 
 an IP protocol' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ ipProtocolNumber $ description
  ) MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.5 NAME 'oncRpc' DESC 'Abstraction of an O
 NC/RPC binding' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ oncRpcNumber $ description ) M
 AY description )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.6 NAME 'ipHost' DESC 'Abstraction of a ho
 st, an IP device' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( cn $ ipHostNumber ) MAY ( l $ desc
 ription $ manager ) )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.7 NAME 'ipNetwork' DESC 'Abstraction of a
 n IP network' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ ipNetworkNumber ) MAY ( ipNetmas
 kNumber $ l $ description $ manager ) )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.8 NAME 'nisNetgroup' DESC 'Abstraction of
  a netgroup' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST cn MAY ( nisNetgroupTriple $ memberNisNe
 tgroup $ description ) )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.9 NAME 'nisMap' DESC 'A generic abstracti
 on of a NIS map' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST nisMapName MAY description )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.10 NAME 'nisObject' DESC 'An entry in a 
 NIS map' SUP top STRUCTURAL MUST ( cn $ nisMapEntry $ nisMapName ) MAY descri
 ption )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.11 NAME 'ieee802Device' DESC 'A device w
 ith a MAC address' SUP top AUXILIARY MAY macAddress )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.12 NAME 'bootableDevice' DESC 'A device 
 with boot parameters' SUP top AUXILIARY MAY ( bootFile $ bootParameter ) )
```